# Usando $_SESSION para troca de imagem temporária

Tags: php, html

Eu estou tentando criar um simulador onde o usuário poderá alterar a imagem, mas quando ele encerrar o Browser, volta a imagem de origem, que esta gravada no BD.

Já andei pesquisando e vi que usando o $_SESSION eu poderia obter o resultado esperado, porém sou muito leigo, e não estou conseguindo obter o resultado.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz de como devo proceder para tal tarefa, ficarei muitíssimo agradecido.

Abaixo o código que estou tentando usar...

```
    <?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["logo"] = "8081.png";
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
    <img width="200" src="img/<?php echo $_SESSION['logo']; ?>" />

    <?php 
    $img = $_SESSION["logo"]["tmp_name"];
    $logo=$_FILES["logo"]["name"]; 
    copy($img,$logo);
    ?>

    <form method="get">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="$_SESSION['logo']"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="logo" value="Atualizar">
    </form>
```

No aguardo de boas dicas, abraços à todos.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar desta forma:

```
session_cache_expire(180000);
session_start();
```

Ou fazer através de cookies:

```
setcookie('logo_cookie', $_SESSION['logo'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24);
```

e na hora de mostrar:

```
$imgArray = $_COOKIE['logo_cookie'];
$img = imgArray["logo"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: Olá Anderson, se você entrar no endereço (http://www.efacilfacil.com), terá uma idéia do que estou precisando. Pois lá explico com mais detalhes, valeu? Abraços.